# ublas: Wrap ublas::vector as ublas::matrix_expression

Tags: c++, boost, ublas

I'm a very noob at Boost::uBLAS.

I have a function which take a `ublas::matrix_expression<double>` as input:

```
namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;

void Func(const ublas::matrix_expression<double>& in,
                ublas::matrix_expression<double>& out);
```

A caller is holding a row vector as `ublas::vector<double>`, and I want it to be passed to `Func`.

Until now I have not found any way to do this. 
What is the best way, preferably without any temporary allocation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is an option to create a read-only adapter of a contiguous area of memory into a **read-only matrix**. Have a look at [example 3](http://www.guwi17.de/ublas/examples/). It is pretty straightforward to use:

```
#include "storage_adaptors.hpp"
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/assignment.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

ublas::vector<double> v(6);
v <<= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
ublas::matrix<double> m = ublas::make_matrix_from_pointer(2, 3, &v(0));
std::cout << m << std::endl;
```

Possibly you could tweak that further to fit your needs/example.

Comment: `make_matrix_from_pointer()` does perform a copy from the source memory.  Also, just clarifying to avoid confusion: It is not part of the boost library.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid allocating if you're ready to sacrifice some multiplication, use

```
outer_prod(scalar_vector<double>(1, 1), vec)
```

to transform vector into matrix expression. Also, your function probably should be

```
template<class C>
void Func(const matrix_expression<C>& in...
```

matrix_expression itself doesn't model matrix expression concept, it's just the base class.