# assign multiple values to boost::numeric::ublas::vector in c++

Tags: c++, boost, vector

I want to know how I can assign multiple values to a vector at once:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;

int main()
{
    vector<double> v1(3);
    v1(0)=0;
    v1(1)=0.1;
    v1(2)=0.05;
    v1(3)=0.25;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to assign all the values at once.
something like:

```
v1 << 0,0.1,0.05,0.25;
```

I tried operator += and there is an error, but I think operator += works for std::vector not boost::....vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at documentation examples http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/samples/assignment_examples.cpp

Basically, you need `v1 <<= 0, 1, 2;`, see more examples in the docs. Unfortunately this library doesn't support initializer_list's yet: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Initializing-from-an-initializer-list-td4647029.html